# How to delete one variable in terminal using git?

Tags: terminal, git, colors

So, I'm having an issue when im trying to use git status in my terminal.

`fatal: bad numeric config value '=' for 'color.ui': invalid unit`

I looked into it and realized I have 2 color.ui variables

```
git config --list
credential.helper=osxkeychain
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
user.name=Charles Pine
user.email=charlespine22@gmail.com
color.ui=auto
color.ui==
```

Does anyone know how to delete the second color.ui? Thanks for all the help in advance. This is one of my first posts, so if i did something wrong i sincerely apologize!

Answer (score 1):

You will probably find that each of these values are set in a different file (i.e: system / global / local)... though it *is* possible for both values to come from one config file.

See the [`git config` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) for more information.

### Location-Based Removal

Try running each of the following, to determine where the errant entry is from:

```bsh
git config --system --get color.ui
git config --global --get color.ui
git config --local  --get color.ui
```

Once you've determined where it's from, remove it by including the `--system` / `--global` / `--local` flag as appropriate. For example, here I unset the local value:

```bsh
git config --local --unset color.ui
```

### Value-Based Removal

If both values are indeed from the same file, then it is possible to also provide the `--unset` mode with a regex pattern that matches the value.

In your case (an `=`), the pattern is fairly safe, but watch out for certain special regex characters, such as:

- `.` - any one character
- `*` - zero or more
- `+` - one or more
- etc...

For you, this should work:

```bsh
git config --unset color.ui =
```

---

When discussing git configuration, the following locations are available:

- `--system` - the system-wide configuration

  - stored in `${prefix}/etc/gitconfig` (`${prefix}` is typically empty)
- `--global` - the user's global configuratio

  - typically either `~/.gitconfig` or `~/.config/git/config`
- `--local` - the repositoriy-specific configuration

  - i.e: `${checkout_root}/.git/config`, though it may be elsewhere if you're in a [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).
- `--file ${filename}` - another file, as specified

---

It is also possible to edit these files by hand - they are text-based with a similar format to [INI files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file). This means that you don't *need* to use the `git config` interface to search for or modify the values.